# Spring Statemachine with JPA sample code and configuration

Tags: spring, persist, spring-statemachine

I am trying to use an RDBMS like MySQL to persist the spring statemachine. i.e. I need to store and retrieve the states of my entities which are controlled by spring statemachine.
I can't seem to find a proper documentation or any sample code that has the entire configuration. All I could find was sample code snippets that doesn't show everything I need to do to persist.
Does anybody have any sample code that shows how to configure spring statemachine on an RDBMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the Persist [Recipe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/sm-persist.html)? It may be useful.

I cannot share my code but here is what you may need

1- Dependencies

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-autoconfigure")
    implementation("org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-starter")
```

2- Code

2.1 Machine configuration (I'm using hard-coded factory strategy)

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory(contextEvents = false)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StateMachineConfig
        extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<S,E >
```

2.2 Persistence configuration

```
@Configuration
public class StateMachinePersistenceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public StateMachineRuntimePersister<S, E, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister(
            final JpaStateMachineRepository jpaStateMachineRepository) {
        return new JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<>(jpaStateMachineRepository);
    }

}
```

2.3 Service Configuration (Allow you to retrieve machines)

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class StateMachineServiceConfig {

    private final StateMachineFactory<S, E> stateMachineFactory;
    private final StateMachineRuntimePersister<S, E, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister;

    @Bean
    public StateMachineService<S, E> stateMachineService() {
        return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(stateMachineFactory, stateMachineRuntimePersister);
    }

}
```

The framework should create a state machine table to allow you to persist state machines